# Java - JFrame, JPanel, Layout, and Clipping

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I have three questions/problems. (NOTE - I don't have enough reputation to post pics, so I linked them. And I needed to obfuscate them...)

1) I created a panel that holds my game graphics (the player area). The panel is supposed to be 800x800 and clip everything that lies below and to the right. But when I add the graphics panel to a JFrame, it doesn't clip. So images go over on the right and left.
This is a picture of how to game starts. Ideally, the graphics would start in this rectangle the whole time:

Picture #1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/idL8f.png

Now, here's what happens when I press play to start.

Picture #2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxtbe.png

How can I set the panel/frame so that the graphics only occupy 800x800 (like the first picture) and everything else is clipped?

2) I'm a bit confused about how I can set up the JFrame. This is how I want it to be layed out:

Picture #3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyJS5.png

How would you lay the JFrame/Panels out? I was thinking BorderLayout, but I'm not certain it would work out.

3) For this game, my class that extends JFrame also contains main(). Is this bad practice?** Are you supposed to not extend JFrame on the main class?

Comment: Edited; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: Do you mean _clipping_, _cropping_ or _scaling_?

Comment: @trashgod: I mean, I want the game to be contained in and show the 800x800 rectangle it's originally in. I don't want the panel to SHOW anything by the 800 pixels in the x and y direction. (So the overflowing images will still be past 800 in each direction, but not displayed.)

Answer (score 4):

1. The easiest way to get an 800x800 panel is to use `setPreferredSize()` and then `pack()` the `JFrame` that contains is. Conveniently, `pack()` "Causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents."

2). See [*A Visual Guide to Layout Managers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for layout suggestions. You can use nested panels to achieve your desired layout.

3). There's nothing *wrong* with extending `JFrame`, but there's little point unless you are modifying the *behavior* of `JFrame`. In contrast, `JPanel` is a convenient container for grouping components; it was *designed* to be extended. You might examine this [example](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) in that regard.

Addendum:

> I don't want the panel to show anything but the 800 pixels in the x and y direction.

You can override `paintComponent()` and copy whatever portion of the image is desired. In the example below, `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null)` draws the top-left 800 pixels of the image, while `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null)` scales the image the panel's size. Note that `f.setResizable(false)` prevents changing the window's size.

Addendum: You can also copy arbitrary portions of the source image to arbitrary areas of the
the destination panel, as shown below. Also consider overriding `getPreferredSize()`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3851847 */
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img;

    public MyPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("../scratch/image.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
//        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 800, 800, null);
//        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 800, 800, 0, 0, 800, 800, this);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("MyPanel");
//        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyPanel().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For #3, what would modifying behavior entail? Does extending vs. instantiating JFrame change how one is allowed to use the JFrame in any way?

Comment: @Dan James: I've added an example based on my understanding of your comment above.